# Calendar event generator from just text

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I would like to have any simple software that given a text like:

```
Meeting with the boss
Tuesday 12th February at 3:00pm
```

it would be able to recognize it as an event and convert it to a calendar event, for example in ICS format, to be used for example with Google Calendar or the Outlook Calendar.

MS Outlook already tries to guess calendar events from text in e-mails, and for a while I just tried to send e-mails to myself containing the text, but this is almost as uncomfortable as generating the calendar event manually.